# How can I make image sit outside bounds from template?

Tags: html, css

I bought a HTML theme from Themeforest:

http://demo.themesurf.com/plumbing/

I am really pleased with it, but I want to make the logo in the upper left hand corner larger and sit outside of the bounds of the `<div>`. Kind of like this:

https://plumbersinsandiego.com

How can I modify the `custom.css` file to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `top` in CSS will set the position of the logo.
Just like this:

```
.navbar-brand {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   z-index: 2; // Don't forgot to put it on the top!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the class "navbar-brand" you can set this CSS properties:

```
position: absolute;
top: 4rem;
z-index: 999;
```